# Javax Response prepends method path when setting Location header path on Status Created

Tags: java, http, jersey, dropwizard

We're using Dropwizard / Jersey to build a web service. The resource has a path and the method has a sub-path. When returning response created (201) the path of the method we're getting is prepended to the location we provide. When returning status OK with a location (contrived I know), all is well, and the location is returned just as we provided it.

How can we return a location that is not a sub-path of the location of our method?

In the example below:
a get to "http://localhost/foo/bar" (created status) responds with location of "http://localhost/foo/bar/wibble" (note the **/foo/bar**)

while a get to "http://localhost/foo/baz" (ok status) responds with location of "http://localhost/wibble" which is what we want.

```
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import java.net.URI;

@Path("/foo")
public class FooResource {

    @POST
    @Path("/bar")
    public Response bar() {

        URI uriOfCreatedResource = URI.create("/wibble");
        return Response.created(uriOfCreatedResource).build();
    }

    @POST
    @Path("/baz")
    public Response baz() {

        URI uriOfCreatedResource = URI.create("/wibble");
        return Response.ok().location(uriOfCreatedResource).build();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Happened to me on GlassFish (JavaEE6).
I think it's a bug, but I never managed to dig the code to the actual URI conversion....

I've found a workaround though:

```
public Response bar(@Context UriInfo info) {
   URI absoluteURI=info.getBaseUriBuilder().path("/wibble").build();
   return Response.created(absoluteURI).build();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that. Our current workaround is to return status 200 with the URL in an object, which gets serialised to JSON.

Answer (score 8):

In case someone stumbles here wondering about this; I dug into Jersey's code to see why this happens. This should explain your problem & Carlo's workaround.

com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse contains this gem:

```
private void setHeaders(MultivaluedMap<String, Object> headers) {
    this.headers = headers;
    Object location = headers.getFirst(HttpHeaders.LOCATION);
    if (location != null) {
        if (location instanceof URI) {
            final URI locationUri = (URI)location;
            if (!locationUri.isAbsolute()) {
                final URI base = (statusType.getStatusCode() == Status.CREATED.getStatusCode())
                        ? request.getAbsolutePath() // WHY!?
                        : request.getBaseUri();
                location = UriBuilder.fromUri(base).
                        path(locationUri.getRawPath()).
                        replaceQuery(locationUri.getRawQuery()).
                        fragment(locationUri.getRawFragment()).
                        build();
            }
            headers.putSingle(HttpHeaders.LOCATION, location);
        }
    }
}
```

In other words: for some reason, someone decided it was a good idea to treat the location header differently if the response status code is 201. Like Carlo noticed, using absolute paths avoids this issue.

Comment: Wow! Thanks for the nice bit of detective work - is the "WHY" comment yours, or in the original source? (ie, do even the Jersey developers think this is odd?)

Comment: I added the WHY to emphasize, I should have been more clear about that :)

Comment: Could it be because specification (http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.2.2) says "with the most specific URI for the resource given by a Location header field"..

Answer (score 0):

In Jersey 2.x the relevant code was completely rewritten and moved to another place. Inside the class `org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime`, the following method is called while writing response data:

```
   private static void ensureAbsolute(final URI location, final MultivaluedMap<String, Object> headers,
                                       final ContainerRequest request) {
        if (location == null || location.isAbsolute()) {
            return;
        }
        // according to RFC2616 (HTTP/1.1), this field can contain one single URI
        headers.putSingle(HttpHeaders.LOCATION, request.getBaseUri().resolve(location));
    }
```

As said earlier, unless the application sets an absolute URI (a URI that starts with a schema like `http:` or `ftp:`) for the Location header, Jersey automatically prepends it with the request's base URI.

It is strange that Jersey does not allow controlling or disabling this behavior.